# getting audio element to play after a pause not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get an audio element to be able to be played and paused as many times as the user hits the button. So far I can get the audio to play after the first push which turns the icon to pause. Then if the user clicks it again it will pause the audio and turn the icon back to a play button. After that I cannot get it to work anymore.

**HTML**

```
<a href="'.$row['audio'].'" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i></a> <a href="#" class="fa fa-play button-play"><audio src="'.$row['audio'].'" id="myTune1" class="myTune1" preload="none"></audio></a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).on("click", ".button-play", function() { 
    var audioElement = $(this).find('.myTune1')[0];
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="fa fa-pause button-pause"><audio src="'+audioElement+'" id="myTune1" class="myTune1" preload="none"></audio></a>');
    audioElement.play();
    thisaudioElement = audioElement;
});
$(document).on("click", ".button-pause", function() { 
    var audioElement = $(this).find('.myTune1')[0];
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).addClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("active");
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="#" class="fa fa-play button-play"><audio src="'+audioElement+'" id="myTune1" class="myTune1" preload="none"></audio></a>');
    thisaudioElement.pause();
});
```

Comment: Can't this entire thing be done with one handler and one button? Click once, add pause class, pause audio, click again remove pause class and add play class. You can check what state it is in by the classes and style the button as you see fit by the pause/play class. I also noticed you addclass active then the next line removes it

Comment: Can u give me a jfiddle example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`audioElement` **is an Object**, you still need to retrieve it's `src` property value from it:

....`src="'+ audioElement.src +'" id="myTune1"`...

Also there's no absolute need to do stuff like

```
$(this).addClass("active");    // Ok.... added but...
$(this).removeClass("active"); // what's this for than
```

### *OK, how to do it than?*

Believe it or not this is all the code you'll possibly need:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".button-play", function( evt ) {
  evt.preventDefault(); // Prevents page scroll to top (since you're using an <a> anchor)
  var audio = $(this).find('audio')[0];
  audio[audio.paused?"play":"pause"]();
  $(this).toggleClass("fa-pause");      // Toggle Pause icon
});
```

```css
.button-play{
  display:inline-block;
  padding:8px 10px;
  line-height:38px;
  text-align:center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#fff;
  background: lime;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.button-play.fa-pause{
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="fa fa-play button-play">
  <audio loop src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/45/ACDC_-_Back_In_Black-sample.ogg" preload="none"></audio>
</a>
```

<sub>P.S: For the future, when you see *similar chunks of code* like the provided one, it's a clear sign that the same can be improved and minimized to the essential.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using one button and one handler

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
    if( $(this).hasClass('play') ) {
        // run play code, remove play class and add pause class
    }
    if( $(this).hasClass('pause') ) {
        // run pause code, remove pause class and add play class
    }
}
```

Plus the `src` issue that's mention in Roko's answer

The look of the button can be styled differently based on the play/pause class

Comment: `hasClass("play")` Why? check directly for the `audio` element `.paused` property :)

Comment: Boom there you go, I have never worked with it so I didn't know